# JavaScript click event not occurring while busy

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I seem to have a concurrency problem of some kind trying to get a click event to occur. The problem is that I am running an animation using `setInterval`, but the stop button is not triggering, probably because the JavaScript is busy. If I click on the "stop" button really fast over and over I can get it to stop. The code looks like this:

```
    var timer_id = null;
    function play(){
        timer_id = setInterval( function(){ 
            time_second++;
            if( time_second == 60 ){
                time_minute++;
                time_second = 0;
            }
            render();
        }, 1000 / time_compression_factor );
        console.log( "timer id: " + timer_id );
    }
    
    function stop(){
        console.log( "stopped" );
        if( timer_id != null );
        clearInterval( timer_id );
        timer_id = null;
    }
    function drawVCRControls(){
        var width_timeslice = 7 + 3;
        var ul_x = 20 + 120 * width_timeslice + 15;
        var ul_y = viewportHeight - 40;
        var pathPlayBack    = "m 20  0  l 10 -8  l  0 16  Z";
        var pathStop        = "m 35 -8  l 16  0  l  0 16  l -16 0 Z";
        var pathPlayForward = "m 57  0  l  0 -8  l 10  8  l -10 8 Z";
        var pathStepBack    = "m 12 20  l 10 -8  l  0 16  Z  m 13 -8  l 5 0  l 0 16  l -5 0 Z";
        var pathPause       = "m 35 12  h 6 v 16  h -6 Z  m 10 0  h 6 v 16  h -6 Z ";
        var pathStepForward = "m 57 12  h 5 v 16  h -5 Z  m  8 0  l 10 8  l -10 8 Z";
        createPath( "vcrPlayBack", ul_x, ul_y, pathPlayBack, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );
        createPath( "vcrStop", ul_x, ul_y, pathStop, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );
        createPath( "vcrPlayForward", ul_x, ul_y, pathPlayForward, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );    
        createPath( "vcrStepBack", ul_x, ul_y, pathStepBack, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );
        createPath( "vcrPause", ul_x, ul_y, pathPause, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );    
        createPath( "vcrStepForward", ul_x, ul_y, pathStepForward, 1, "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );
        vcrPlayForward.addEventListener( "click", function(){
            play();
        }, false );
        vcrStop.addEventListener( "click", function(){
            stop();
        }, false );
    }
```

The `render()` call in the `play()` function draws a lot of stuff, so I think when it is busy drawing it is essentially ignoring the click event on the vcrStop button. I can see this because I have a console.log statement that records whenever `stop()` gets called and it is not getting called when I click the vcrStop button.

I know the handler is operating correctly because if I click the vcrStop button *before* starting the animation it gets logged to the console.

Note that if I run the interval at 1 second then everything works fine, but the shorter the interval is, the harder it is to stop the animation. For example if I use a 500ms interval I might have to click two or three times to stop it, but if I use a 100ms interval (the desired interval), I have to click really fast 10 times or more.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How large is timeslice? If it is 10 or greater it is very likely that the UI gets locked by the JS execution. Try to set it really low and see if it works. If it does, then you have your solution there :) And then you can go on to use more CSS animations.

Comment: Normally the speed up factor is 10, so the interval is 100 milliseconds. This might be too fast.

Comment: Why do you add the eventListener on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have a JSFiddle for your specific problem, that would be very helpful.

I think your problem is exactly what you state - the script is busy. The thing is that JavaScript is executed in a single threaded manor. Thus, the click event can only be handled after the rendering is done. To make a cancellation of the rendering possible, you could split your rendering in several steps and call each in a chained callback, i.e., after the first one is done, call the second step of rendering if and only if the process was not cancelled.

Anyways, you mention that you have a console.log for the click. After the rendering is done, do you see the log's output?

Comment: No, the event is getting thrown away. Like if I quickly click the stop button 20 times, there will no console output until I get lucky and an event gets processed, then just that ONE event gets logged. So, the events are not getting queued, they are getting discarded.

Comment: How can I modify the rendering to check if the process was "cancelled"? If the button click is not getting handled then I have no way to known if it was cancelled. In Java there is a Thread.yield command to give a chance to the event queue but there is no such queue in JS.

Comment: JavaScript execution locks the UI. Try to set the interval to 2 seconds and check again.

Comment: You might want to look at Web Workers: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp and http://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20Workers for compatibility

Comment: No, web workers do not have access to the DOM. You normally do the manipulation afterwards or in increments. So you listen to the onmessage event of the Web Worker and change the DOM based on the event information, see the w3schools link I added before!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may be right, the **render()** may be blocking the **click** event to be triggered. But also the click event takes some time to triggered as it's a combination of **mousedown** and **mouseup** events. Which may be greater than your interval. You can try with **mousedown** event which I think takes lesser time than click to bubble.

Good luck